# Using VS Code for working with STM32 Projects

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, stm32

I want to use VS Code to edit STM32 Projects. I don't want to build them or create new projects with it. I just want to edit them. So it would be great to get rid of all the error squiggles I have right now..

[image]

Also .h files like <stddef.h> are missing or I can not open the uint8_t declaration what should be inside the <stdint.h> I guess?

This is an example of how my Inc. File is looking right now.

I already installed the extension "STM32-for-vscode" but this only solved some of the paths.

Did somebody else already set up his vscode with the cube IDE and got rid of these error squiggles everywhere?

Comment: Not the best decision. To play with vs-code -yes. To write STM32 softwasre - no

Comment: What OS? VScode is expecting you have `gcc-arm-none-eabi` (or equivalent) installed that provides the needed system libraries and headers. If on Linux, your distribution likely already provides a package for you.

Comment: Actually the solution was pretty simple..

In the stm32-for-vscode extension there is a "run Cube IDE importer" option that needs to be run. After that you need to execute the "Clean Build" option and then it was working.